# How can I limit an Active Directory user to only use mstsc

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I would like to create a domain user with the sole permission to run the MSTSC program, or activate RDP from a desktop icon. 
I don't want that user to be able to do anything else on the server he will be accessing. 
Is this possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with group policy. Create an ou and link a Group policy to it. You can try the link for more info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811966.aspx